# SQL get names between 2 dates but keep any previous dates as well

Tags: sql

Im not sure if im asking the question right or not but this is the data i have

```
id  |  Name  |   date
-----------------------
1   | jim    |  10/3/20
1   | jim    |  10/20/20
1   | jim    |  10/23/20
2   | mike   |  10/3/20
2   | mike   |  10/16/20
2   | mike   |  10/30/20
3   | bob    |  10/30/20
3   | bob    |  10/31/20
```

and i want to pull names that were entered on the dates 10/30/20 - 10/31/20 but also keep all the previous dates of those people

```
id  |  Name  |   date
-----------------------
2   | mike   |  10/3/20
2   | mike   |  10/16/20
2   | mike   |  10/30/20
3   | bob    |  10/30/20
3   | bob    |  10/31/20
```

this is what i got so far which pulls only data between those dates

SELECT
id,
name,
date
FROM
People
WHERE
date BETWEEN '10/30/20' AND '10/31/20'
ORDER BY
date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.id = t.id and
                    t2.date >= '2020-10-30' and
                    t2.date < '2020-11-01'
             );
```